# Change column names by looking up new names in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a set of column names ("A", "B"):

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2), B=c(1,3))
```

I want to exchange the column names with new ones, which are provided in a new dataframe:

```
new.names <- data.frame(Old=c("A","B"), New=c("C","D"))
```

I want R to browse `new.names$Old` for matches in `colnames(df)` and exchange `colnames(df)` with what it has found in `new.names$New`. It is basically a variant of excel's vlookup.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `match`

```
colnames(df) = new.names$New[match(colnames(df), new.names$Old)]
```